# How to improve performance of query in Google Cloud Datastore via Djangae?

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, djangae

I would like to know how to improve query performance in a table with around 100000 records, using Google Cloud Datastore and Djangae. Thank you in advance.

**Model**

```
class Species(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    scientific_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, db_index=True)       
    common_name_en = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    common_name_es = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    common_name_fr = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{self.scientific_name}".format(**locals())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "species"
```

**Admin**

```
class SpeciesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    admin_caching_enabled = True
    list_per_page = 10
    fields = ['scientific_name']
    list_display = ['scientific_name']
    readonly_fields = (
        'scientific_name',
    )
```

After trying the following queries from the shell the response takes too long.
**Query 1**

```
result = Species.objects.order_by('scientific_name')[0:1].get()
```

**Query 2**

```
result = Species.objects.all()[:5].get()
```

**Query breakdown from Django Admin**
[image]